# Date and Format issues in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new here and this is my first question. Well, here it goes:

What I need to do is to create a PHP that compares an array of birthdays (dates) from a database (mysqli query) to the actual date (particularly month and day, ignoring the year for obvious reasons) so it can confirm "This person's birthday is today" through an echo or something.

I am having trouble formatting the date from the sql array. Here's what I got so far:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "employees");
$actualdate = date('md');


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT BirthDate FROM Birthdays";


if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {

        if (in_array($actualdate, $row)) {
        echo "Birthday!";
        } else {
        echo "No birthday";         
        }

     }

     mysqli_free_result($result);
}

mysqli_close($enlace);

?>
```

Thanks beforehand, and sorry for the botherations.

Comment: check `var_dump($row);` and show us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume BirthDate is stored as a DATE. I would probably only select the Birthdays that are today:

```
SELECT BirthDate 
FROM Birthdays 
WHERE DAY(BirthDate) = DAY(NOW()) AND MONTH(BirthDate) = MONTH(NOW());
```

Comment: best possible solution

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to echo "No birthday" you need to check the date format in the database. Normally the date format in the MySQL is **YYYY-MM-DD**. So you need to change the date creation code to

```
$actualdate = date('Y-m-d');
```

That will do.. Otherwise you can choose @jim's answer, to get only today's birthdays.